# Jquery-ui draggable glitch?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Hi I am trying to make a scroll bar (I'm still far from done, link here: http://jsfiddle.net/xD2Hy/24/ ), thing is that when I scroll (using the scroll bar) to the bottom, THEN and I resize the window to make it SMALLER, the scrollbar drowns under the window. To fix this, i tried adding a jquery offset to the scroll bar move it up when i resize. NOW when i scroll to bottom, then i resize, the scroll bar dissapears completely! I really dont know what to do, im still learning javascript, please help. Here's a the offset jquery of the code, check the link of the jsfiddle for the whole thing:

```
$('#scrollBar').offset({top:100});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're setting offset to 100px from document's top border. You need to set offset based on scrollbar's parent container offset and height, and scrollbar container's height. Try this instead:

```
var scrollContainer = $('#cow'),
    scrollBar = $('#scrollBar');

scrollBar.offset({ top: scrollContainer.offset().top + scrollContainer.height() - scrollBar.height() });
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xD2Hy/30/)